# Full Width Container Colour Problems

Tags: widgets, content, formatting, static-website

I wanted to duplicate a page and so I copied the code into a new page. Everything worked however one full-width container has a background colour that on the original page stretched across the whole screen but doesn't on the new page. I have exhausted all options I can think of, I have checked and re checked to code, changed all the options and put them back but nothing seems to have worked. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Your problem is very specific and it seems it is not possible to help without inspecting your site. You should check from where the css is coming from and if it is included in the new page.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what you are talking about without code, but seams like you could check if those pages use different options in plugin like background manager.

Comment: This should be comment rather than answer.